# How to set maximum value in Data bar in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a data in excel as shown in the image. I would like to add Data bars using conditional formatting for Column B. But the problem is for 60% the entire cell got filled. For 60%, nearer to half of cell must be filled and same for other values. I tried to use the maximum percent as 100%. But it is not working for me.How to solve that. Help me

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually i found the answer. Adding dummy cell value in C1 = 100% will works. Then in formatting just fix the maximum as formula =($C$1)*1.

Comment: But this is not a solution, this is a workaround!!! What you have done is a "hack" to get around to the solution, but I HIGHLY recommend to perform the proper solution, as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48459695

Answer (score 3):

Go to Conditonal formatting, data bars, more rules, maximum->number, value=1